How to extract the index of a character's nth occurrence from input string in cosmos DB?
I'm trying to extract different parts of an string input based on the occurrence of a character. Using SUBSTRING and INDEX_OF I was able to extract the first part of the my string.
select 'abc_def_ghij_20230108100000_20230108100000_20240517105347' as input,
INDEX_OF('abc_def_ghij_20230108100000_20230108100000_20240517105347', '_'),
substring('abc_def_ghij_20230108100000_20230108100000_20240517105347', 0, INDEX_OF('abc_def_ghij_20230108100000_20230108100000_20240517105347', '_')) as 'first_part'

Next, I'm trying to include RegExMatch() into my INDEX_OF() function so that I could get the index when numbers starts to appear my string input. But clearly I'm doing something wrong:
select 'abc_def_ghij_20230108100000_20230108100000_20240517105347' as input,
INDEX_OF('abc_def_ghij_20230108100000_20230108100000_20240517105347', '_'),
SUBSTRING('abc_def_ghij_20230108100000_20230108100000_20240517105347', 0, INDEX_OF('abc_def_ghij_20230108100000_20230108100000_20240517105347', '_')) as 'first_part',
substring('abc_def_ghij_20230108100000_20230108100000_20240517105347', INDEX_OF('abc_def_ghij_20230108100000_20230108100000_20240517105347', '_'), INDEX_OF('abc_def_ghij_20230108100000_20230108100000_20240517105347', RegexMatch("abc_def_ghij_20230108100000_20230108100000_20240517105347", "[0-9]"))) as 'date_part'

Where am I messing up the RegexMatch() ?

You might want to look at RegExMatch(). Substring() doesn't support regex (plus the third parameter is for length, not an expression). Please edit to provide specifics (including expected vs actual output, and errors) - right now it's an improperly-formed use of substring() and "is not working."

also - you might want to consider changing your schema if you're storing many discrete properties inside one giant string...

RegexMatch returns a boolean. Don't think that'll be of any use when trying to extract the data from the string. Maybe it's possible with available string functions, but otherwise this could easily be done with a user defined function and RegExp. Big downside is that the UDF can't leverage your indexing policy (for performance), but depending how you use it that might not matter.
